# How to modify TYPO3 System Category description field to RTE-field

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 7.6, I'm trying to convert the backend's System Category's "description" field into an RTE-field. Does anyone know if and how I should do this? If I could simply alter the tca for that field somewhere, I would have what I need, but I'm guessing it's not that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create, for example in your extension, the file

```
Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_category.php
```

File content:

```
 <?php
   defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

   $tempColumns = [
    'description' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.description',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 40,
            'rows' => 15,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ),
        'defaultExtras' => 'richtext[]:rte_transform[mode=ts_links]'
    ),
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'sys_category',
    $tempColumns,
    1
);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, this is very helpful information! In fact, this way you can alter all kinds of system fields..... -Thanks!